# How to efficiently create large number of QWidget?

Tags: qt

For some reason, I am forced to create a large number of QWidgets either at the start of my program or during the user's usage.
And that will always cause the main thread to stuck for several seconds.
How could I improve the creation speed? Should I make these widgets simpler (like remove the pushbutton's pixmap and keep minimum functionality?)

Comment: Are you adding these widgets to a widget that, itself, is visible? This is known to be slow.

Comment: Yes..any possible way out?

Comment: You could try `setUpdatesEnabled(false)` before your changes, and re-enable them after.

Comment: I have tried. Still slow...

Comment: Do you create the widgets with a parent, or parentless and add them later via a layout? The Qt Doc states at one point the latter is recommended, but I had problems with that approch myself (new windows created visible shortly, for every widget...)

Comment: Could be `QGraphicsView` an alternative to your `QWidget` approach? See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-chip-example.html

Comment: You never need to create more widgets than are visible at any given time, and it's not really necessary to create very small widgets - so you should rearchitect your solution. Perhaps you need to tell us what "some reason" for the creation of so many widgets (how many??) is, and what exactly are those widgets. If you have more than about a hundred visible widgets, the UI design is wrong anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no efficient and simple way to break the laws of physics. Many UI elements == slow, there is no way around it.

Workarounds: Reuse existing UI elements to give the impression of scrolling. So instead of creating 10'000 UI elements to display a table with 10 columns and 1'000 rows, just create enough to fill the screen and move the data when the user scrolls - just giving the impression that the UI is scrolling. This approach is driven by the fact that screen space is limited and there is little to be gained by adding UI elements that you can't see.

The other approach is to create only a few elements at a time, always giving the UI thread time between "batches" to respond. For this approach, create N elements and then add a timer event. When the timer fires, add another N elements and so forth until you have created enough.

The drawback of the second approach is that your OS eventually kills you since resources are limited. If you create 100'000 UI elements and each needs 10 KB of RAM, then the application will allocate 1 GB of RAM just for the UI.