# A large number of dynamically updated widgets in the Qt

Tags: qt, widget, chat, real-time

I'm writing a simple messenger in Qt for educational purposes. I need to develop a widget that will contain messages. It should look something like this:

```
MyChatWidget : (may be) QFrame + QVBoxLayout
    --- MyMessageWidget : (may be) QLabel
    --- MyMessageWidget : (may be) QLabel
    --- MyMessageWidget : (may be) QLabel
    --- ...
```

And `QScrollBar` or `QScrollArea` above for global scrolling.

So here's the problem I'm facing.

Theoretically, a chat can contain millions of messages. Creating, deleting, updating and storing large numbers of widgets can be very expensive. Therefore, as far as I understand, the developers use the following trick (for example mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30351799/how-to-efficiently-create-large-number-of-qwidget)) :

The main widget contains a fixed number of child widgets. Some of them may even be invisible. As the user scrolls through content, message widgets update, creating the illusion of movement. In this case, messages are loaded into the cache, but only those that are needed at the moment are displayed on the interface.

Developing such a system is difficult for a beginner. Before I dive into programming, I want to make sure I understand the problem statement correctly. There may be some important tips that I should pay attention to. Perhaps there is some generally accepted solution or even a set of lightweight libraries that will help me a lot.

I would be very grateful for any advice, as developing and testing such a system blindly could take me several weeks.

Comment: Have you explored model/view programming? incl. controls like `QTableView`?

Comment: @Atmo I know about MVC pattern, but haven't worked much with the `QTableView`. Should I use it in my case?

Comment: I believe you should give it a try. For the same amount of data shown, `QTableView` manages the displayed data itself (relying on the model to provide it quickly) and should take less resource than thousands of widgets, even if just `QLabel`s. In terms of useful methods for your use case (at first glance), `QAbstractItemModel` there are `beginInsertRows` / `endInsertRows` (trigger signals about data being appended), and `canFetchMore`/`fetchMore` for models that are populated incrementally.

Comment: On a different note, you should consider removing old messages (incl. calls to `beginRemoveRows`/`endRemoveRows`) after a while: 1M messages (let alone [quote] "*millions of messsages*") takes 9 months to reach at a pace of 1 message / second without any pause aka months worth of reading. You may want to have them saved on disk, with the model being able to retrieve them if the user scrolls up but I doubt you want them in memory at all times. `QTableView` and `QListView` can easily accomodate thousands of lines (even with a delegate to make it look "chat-like").

Comment: @Atmo Thank you very much for the advice. I don't have a full understanding yet, but what you're saying makes a lot more sense. I'll try to use this approach.

Comment: When you have the start of a working code and are blocked somewhere, post another question with minimal reproducible example. This one was most likely too broad for the site, hence why nobody else answered.

Comment: I was thinking about widgets because the message is a complex structure. It can have an image, text and a set of buttons. In my understanding, QTableView was intended for simple data. But as I now see from examples, this is wrong.

Comment: Classes inheriting `QAbstractItemDelegate` can paint anything and tell the view hoow much space they need for that. If you have only 1 column, use `QListView`

Comment: @Atmo Thanks again. I understand that the question is very abstract, but perhaps you saved me from an obviously dead-end solution.